# self defined combination function in Scala

Tags: scala, combinations, combinatorics

I want to implement a combination function in scala and my code is as below:

```
def combination[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] ={
    (n, ls) match{
        case (_, Nil) => List(Nil)
        case (1, _) => ls.map(List(_))
        case (_, _) if n > ls.size => List.empty
        case _ => ls.flatMap(x => combination(n - 1, subList(x, ls)).map(x :: _))
      }
  }
def subList[A](e: A, in: List[A]) = in.takeRight(in.size - in.indexOf(e) - 1)
```

but the result is not what I expect. When I call `combination(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f)`. it will give me those results with one or two elements like List('d, 'f), List('f) and so on. Can anyone help me to find the issue? Thanks.

**Update**: 
the correct version is

```
def combination[A](n: Int, ls: List[A]): List[List[A]] ={
    (n, ls) match{
        case (_, Nil) => Nil
        case (1, _) => ls.map(List(_))
        case (_, _) if n > ls.size => Nil
        case _ => ls.flatMap(x => combination(n - 1, subList(x, ls)).map(x :: _))
      }
  }
def subList[A](e: A, in: List[A]) = in.takeRight(in.size - in.indexOf(e) - 1)
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Not sure if you meant to type `combination` instead of `combination2` in the last case

Comment: sorry for misleading. its a typo and it should call combination

Comment: the expected output should be List(List('a, 'b, 'c), List('a, 'b, 'd)) and so on

Comment: With `subList[A](x: A, ls: List[A]) = ls.filterNot(_ == x)`, the invocation of `combination(3, (1 to 6).toList)` gives `  List(1, 2, 3),
  List(1, 2, 4),
  List(1, 2, 5),
  List(1, 2, 6),
  List(1, 3, 2),
  List(1, 3, 4),
  List(1, 3, 5),
  List(1, 3, 6),
  List(1, 4, 2),
  List(1, 4, 3),
  List(1, 4, 5),
  List(1, 4, 6),
  List(1, 5, 2),
  List(1, 5, 3),
  List(1, 5, 4)` and a whole bunch of other combinations. It does not give any results with one or two elements.

Comment: thanks for all help. The issue is in `case (_, Nil) => List(Nil)`. It should be `case (_, Nil) => Nil`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Too many cases, unnecessary complicated `combinations2` and `subList`.

---

Recall how [*combinations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination) are defined. If you have a set `{a1, ..., aN}`, and you want to select `k` elements from this set, then you can do essentially just *two* things:

- You don't include `a1` into the subset. Then you have to select `k` elements from the remaining `{a2, ..., aN}`.
- You include `a1` into the subset. Then you have to select `k-1` elements from `{a2, ..., aN}`, and add `a0` to those `k-1` elements.

That's where the formula

```
C(N, k) =         C(N - 1, k) + C(N - 1, k - 1)
```

comes from.

Translated into code, this is just:

```
def comb[A](ls: List[A], k: Int): List[List[A]] = {
  if (k == 0) List(Nil)
  else ls match {
    case Nil => List()
    case h :: t => comb(t, k) ++ comb(t, k - 1).map(h :: _)
  }
}
```

Example:

```
comb(List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e), 3) foreach println
```

gives:

```
List('c, 'd, 'e)
List('b, 'd, 'e)
List('b, 'c, 'e)
List('b, 'c, 'd)
List('a, 'd, 'e)
List('a, 'c, 'e)
List('a, 'c, 'd)
List('a, 'b, 'e)
List('a, 'b, 'd)
List('a, 'b, 'c)
```

Comment: I totally understand you solution. could you tell me what is the issue for my code?

Comment: @tomcy Because of the `flatMap`, your code produces gigantic lists with every permutation of every combination, because there is a branching factor of `n` for list of length `n`. In my code, there is a recursive branching factor of at most `2`.

Answer (score 0):

In the last case you are calling `combination2`. If you change to `combination` (with reasonable definition of `subList`) it works. I guess this is something remaining from an intermediate version.

Comment: it should call combination. its a typo

Comment: Yes, what I say is that this typo is probably the only problem. If you remove it and have correct definition of `subList` (this is another possible problem) you'll get the correct result (for ordered combinations).

Comment: If you only want unordered combinations, see Andrey's answer instead.

Answer (score 0):

There's a much simpler way of doing this

```
def comb[A](n: Int, ls:List[A]): List[List[A]] = {
  if(ls.isEmpty) List(Nil)
  else ls.toSet[A].subsets.map(_.toList).filter(_.length == n).toList
}
```

[Scala fiddle](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/dqfhFfi/1)

Comment: It has exponential time and space requirements, and I'm somehow missing the 'self' in the 'self defined' part. Why are you treating `n == 0` separately?

Comment: Without treating `n == 0` separately, something like `comb(0, List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))` returns `List(List())` instead of just `List()` - if that's expected, then the `if` statement can be taken out. I wasn't sure what OP meant by "self defined" - if they meant "recursive" then a different solution would definitely be more appropriate.

Comment: The set `{1,2,3,4,5}` contains one subset of size `0`, namely `{}`. Thus, for `n=0`, it should return `List(List())`. I assume that by "self defined" the OP meant that (s)he wants to do it without relying on any other combinatoric methods provided by the standard library.

Comment: As previously stated, if this is unnecessary it could always be taken out. OP didn't specify what they wanted for `n == 0`, and "should" is subjective. To be fair though, after re-reading the original question that `if` statement should  really be `if(ls.isEmpty) List(Nil)`.